# Material UI Autocomplete unique id problem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i have the same names in my data and I want to use unique id which i have .
However . i can not find right place for "key={id}"

```
<AutoCompleteComp
          data={data}
          setInputValue={setInputValue}
          inputValue={inputValue}
          setCurrentEvent={setCurrentEvent}
          goToPage={goToPage}
        />
        {currentEvent?.name === inputValue && (
          <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
            {listArray.map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem
                // selected
                onClick={() => addUrlHandler(index, text)}
                button
                key={text}
                sx={{
                  "& .MuiListItemText-root": {
                    color: index === currentIndex ? "#6AE05F" : "",
                  },
                  "&:hover": {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(36, 82, 32, 0.5)",
                  },
                }}>
                <ListItemIcon sx={{ color: "#6AE05F" }}>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText sx={{ color: "white" }} primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use `index` as `key` when you can't find an id.

This is from the doc:

> When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the
> item index as a key as a last resort:

```
<AutoCompleteComp
          data={data}
          setInputValue={setInputValue}
          inputValue={inputValue}
          setCurrentEvent={setCurrentEvent}
          goToPage={goToPage}
        />
        {currentEvent?.name === inputValue && (
          <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
            {listArray.map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem
                // selected
                onClick={() => addUrlHandler(index, text)}
                button
                key={index}
                sx={{
                  "& .MuiListItemText-root": {
                    color: index === currentIndex ? "#6AE05F" : "",
                  },
                  "&:hover": {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(36, 82, 32, 0.5)",
                  },
                }}>
                <ListItemIcon sx={{ color: "#6AE05F" }}>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText sx={{ color: "white" }} primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i do have id the problem is whatever i put to key gives me error : "Keys should be unique".